# How to change line shape's color in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I tried every method to do that. But nothing works. Please, help me, how can I add line in Excel and change its color in C#? I tried this:

```
Shape line = ws.Shapes.AddLine(98, 60, 432, 60);
line.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color.Red.ToArgb();
```

But it gives me error: out of range. What can I do else?)

Comment: A line shape has a border color, not a fill color

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the fore color of the right object. Here's the fix:

```
Shape line = ws.Shapes.AddLine(98, 60, 432, 60);
line.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Color.Red.ToArgb();
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this help:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

Where msoThemeColorAccent2 is the color change